# How to show maps on half screen in Android using geo URI?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, geolocation, uri

I am using following code to show my location on google maps

```
String uri ="geo:" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() + "?z=" + 3;
intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it shows map on whole screen, which I don't want. Is it possible to show map on half screen of your android phone without using `com.google.android.maps.MapView` or without importing maps library to my project.
Plz help me out if any one knows the solution.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a Custom `MapActivity`, that is create a `Activity` that extends `MapActivity` and plot the points with `xml` having `MapView` with half of the screen, what you are using is `Androids` `inbuilt` way of displaying Map. By, this way you won't be able to show the Map in half of the screen.